# Failing to reproduce a basic Stan example due to numerical precision

Tags: floating-point, simulation, stan

I'm attempting to reproduce the example in Section 15.2-15.3 in the Stan manual, version 2.11:

gpdemo.stan

```
/*
 * Stan manual, ch. 15
 */

data {
  int<lower=1> N;
  real x[N];
}


transformed data {
  vector[N] mu;
  cov_matrix[N] Sigma;
  matrix[N, N] L;

  for (i in 1:N)
    mu[i] = 0;

  for (i in 1:N)
    for (j in 1:N)
      Sigma[i, j] = exp(-square(x[i] - x[j])) + i == j ? 0.1 : 0.0;
  L = cholesky_decompose(Sigma);
}


parameters {
  vector[N] z;
}


model {
  z ~ normal(0, 1);
}


generated quantities {
  vector[N] y;
  y = mu + L * z;
}
```

gpdemo.R

```
library('rstan')

x <- -50:50 / 10

data <- list(
  N = length(x),
  x = x
)

sim <- stan("gp-demo.stan", "gp_demo", data = data, iter = 200, chains = 3)
```

But Stan complains that `Sigma` is not positive definite:

```
Error : Exception thrown at line 23: cholesky_decompose: Matrix m is not positive definite
failed to create the sampler; sampling not done
```

And in fact it isn't:

```
x_dist <- as.matrix(dist(x))
x_kernel <- exp(-x_dist^2)
eigen(x_kernel)$values
# [1] FALSE
```

but the issue seems to be one of numerical precision rather than anything else:

```
summary(eigen(x_kernel)$values)
#      Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
#  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000  0.000049 17.360000 
min(eigen(x_kernel)$values)
# [1] -1.125251e-15
```

Obviously this example runs without numerical problems on *someone*'s machine (otherwise it wouldn't be in the manual, let alone reproduced on blogs all over the Internet). This is a very simple example, so I'm wondering if I'm just making a mistake somewhere.

For what it's worth, I was able to get this to work by looping more judiciously to construct `Sigma`:

```
for (i in 1:N) Sigma[i, i] = 1.1;
for (i in 1:(N-1))
  for (j in (i+1):N) {
    Sigma[i, j] = exp(-square(x[i] - x[j]));
    Sigma[j, i] = Sigma[i, j];
}
```

Comment: The things in the manual aren't necessarily run on anyone's computer but even if they are, the results can differ numerically from those on a different computer. Your version is better, although there is now a `cov_exp_quad()` function in the Stan language that you should use instead.

Comment: First, the R code you've used is wrong. It should be:
```
x_dist <- as.matrix(dist(x))
x_kernel <- exp(-x_dist^2) + diag(length(x)) * 0.1
eigen(x_kernel)$values
```

Regarding the Stan program, I'm not sure how tightly the ternary operator binds. In the loop, it might be interpreting it as:
```
Sigma[i, j] = exp(-square(x[i] - x[j])) + i == (j ? 0.1 : 0.0);
```
instead of
```
Sigma[i, j] = exp(-square(x[i] - x[j])) + (i == j ? 0.1 : 0.0);
```

Can you try putting in explicit parentheses? [sorry -- all the formatting doesn't work in the comment]

Comment: @syclik thanks for the notes. Adding to the diagonal in R doesn't change the problem. And I took the ternary operator example right from the example. I've since moved on to other methods (eg switching to cov_exp_quad as per Ben's note), but I can update the question. BTW you can use single tickmarks to get in-line code formatting in comments.